# Combining 2 dictionaries into one Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries, one associates building code to bldg name

```
Dct_1 = {'1': ['Bldg 1'], '2': ['Bldg 2'], '3': ['Bldg 3'], '4': ['Bldg 4'], '5': ['Bldg 5']...})
```

the second associates building code to floor and tenant

```
Dct_2 = {'1': [('Floor 0', 'Ten 1'), ('Floor 1', 'Ten 2'), ('Floor 3', 'Ten 3')], '2': [('Floor 1', 'Ten A'), ('Floor 2', 'Ten B')...]}
```

I am trying to write a function to create a 3rd dct to associate floor and tenant to bldg name.

```
bldg_floor_tenant_dct = {'Bldg 1': [('Floor 0', 'Ten 1'), ('Floor 1', 'Ten 2'), ('Floor 3', 'Ten 3')], 'Bldg 2': [('Floor 1', 'Ten A'), ('Floor 2', 'Ten B')] ...}
```

is what I am trying to get.

I have tried the following 2 functions, the first returns an error and the second does nothing

```
bldg_floor_tenant_dct = {}
for facilities_code, building_name in Dct_1.iteritems():
    floors = Dct_2[facilities_code]
    for k(floor_num, floor_dept) in floors:
        b_data = bldg_floor_tenant_dct.get(building_name, [])
        b_data.append({floor_num: floor_num,
            dept: floor_dept})

print bldg_floor_tenant_dct
```

error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

and the second:

```
bldg_floor_tenant_dct = defaultdict(list)
for keys in Dct_1:
    if Dct_1.keys() == Dct_2.keys():
        bldg_floor_tenant_dct[Dct_1.values()].append(Dct_2.values())
        print bldg_floor_tenant_dct
        break
```

What am I missing or is there a better way to write this?

Comment: "I am trying to write a function to create a 3rd dct to associate floor and tenant to bldg name" <- please post your expected result instead of giving a vague description.

Comment: `for k(floor_num, floor_dept) in floors:` What is this supposed to do? I don't think you're allowed to have function calls and arguments and things in between `for` and `in`.

Comment: Is there a one-to-one mapping of building code to building name in Dct_1? Having lists for the values (e.g. `{'1': ['Bldg 1'], ...}`) implies that there can be more than one building name per code... If it is one-to-one you should remove the list, i.e. `{'1': 'Bldg 1', ...}`

Comment: The reason it is a Dct_1 is a dictionary of lists is there is a "N/A" building code for unassigned buildings and they need a place for this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dict-comprehension. Demo for shortened `Dct_1` and `Dct_2`:

```
>>> Dct_1 = {'1': ['Bldg 1'], '2': ['Bldg 2']}
>>> Dct_2 = {'1': [('Floor 0', 'Ten 1'), ('Floor 1', 'Ten 2'), ('Floor 3', 'Ten 3')], '2': [('Floor 1', 'Ten A'), ('Floor 2', 'Ten B')]}
>>> {v[0]:Dct_2[k] for k,v in Dct_1.items()}
{'Bldg 2': [('Floor 1', 'Ten A'), ('Floor 2', 'Ten B')], 'Bldg 1': [('Floor 0', 'Ten 1'), ('Floor 1', 'Ten 2'), ('Floor 3', 'Ten 3')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
for k(floor_num, floor_dept) in floors:
```

the `k(floor_num, floor_dept)` looks like a function to python and you can't assign a variable to a function in this way. Instead try

```
for floor_num, floor_dept in floors:
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why but your solution seem complicated. I would have write it like this:

```
Dct_1 = {'1': ['Bldg 1'], '2': ['Bldg 2'], '3': ['Bldg 3'], '4': ['Bldg 4'], '5': ['Bldg 5']}
Dct_2 = {'1': [('Floor 0', 'Ten 1'), ('Floor 1', 'Ten 2'), ('Floor 3', 'Ten 3')], '2': [('Floor 1', 'Ten A'), ('Floor 2', 'Ten B')]}

result = {}

for key, value in Dct_2.iteritems():
    for item in value:
        if key in Dct_1 and Dct_1[key]:
            result[item] = Dct_1[key]

print result
```

Comment: This works but it creates a separate entry for each tenant floor combo. If there are multiple tenants on a floor it will create a separate entry instead of multiple tenants for a single building floor entry.